# Iterating across rows in a dataframe and reading values

Tags: r

I have  r dataframe df1

```
    $ date            <date> 2005-01-01, 2005-01-01
    $ realtime_period <date> 2005-04-28, 2006-02-28
    $ GDP             <dbl> 12182.7, 12198.8
```

And another r dataframe d2

```
    $ ID                     <dbl> 65, 99, 411, 420, 421, 426, 428, 429, 431, 433, 446, 448, 456, 463, 472, 483, 484, 497, 498, 502, 504, 5...
    $ forecast               <dbl> 12113.86, 12224.00, 12126.00, 12138.00, 12110.60, 12166.76, 12149.40, 12151.10, 12155.73, 12142.60, 1213...
```

And I want to read each row in df1 and add a corresponding column to df2, and include the corresponding value in the "GDP" column in df2

```
df2[paste(as.character(df1$realtime_period), "-", df2$GDP)] <- df1$GDP
```

```
$ ID                     <dbl> 65, 99, 411, 420, 421, 426, 428, 429, 431, 433, 446, 448, 456, 463, 472, 483, 484, 497, 498, 502, 504, 5...
$ forecast               <dbl> 12113.86, 12224.00, 12126.00, 12138.00, 12110.60, 12166.76, 12149.40, 12151.10, 12155.73, 12142.60, 1213...
$ `2005-04-28 - 12182.7` <dbl> 12182.7, 12198.8, 12182.7, 12198.8, 12182.7, 12198.8, 12182.7, 12198.8, 12182.7, 12198.8, 12182.7, 12198...
$ `2006-02-28 - 12198.8` <dbl> 12198.8, 12182.7, 12198.8, 12182.7, 12198.8, 12182.7, 12198.8, 12182.7, 12198.8, 12182.7, 12198.8, 12182...
```

But the values are mixed up. For example, all the values in `2005-04-28 - 12182.7` column should read 12182.7, but every other value is mixed up with the corresponding value in the next column

The expected outcome is as follows

```
$ ID                     <dbl> 65, 99, 411, 420, 421, 426, 428, 429, 431, 433, 446, 448, 456, 463, 472, 483, 484, 497, 498, 502, 504, 5...
$ forecast               <dbl> 12113.86, 12224.00, 12126.00, 12138.00, 12110.60, 12166.76, 12149.40, 12151.10, 12155.73, 12142.60, 1213...
$ `2005-04-28 - 12182.7` <dbl> 12182.7, 12198.8, 12182.7, 12198.8, 12182.7, 12182.7, 12182.7, 12182.7, 12182.7, 12182.7, 12182.7, 12182...
$ `2006-02-28 - 12198.8` <dbl> 12198.8, 12198.8, 12198.8, 12198.8, 12198.8, 12198.8, 12198.8, 12198.8, 12198.8, 12198.8, 12198.8, 12198...
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you share data using `dput` and show expected output for the same? Read how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @RonakShah I added the expected outcome. What I simply want is to read the corresponding value on df1 and list down the same value in all rows within the corresponding column on df2

Comment: You're getting caught by vector recycling. You need it, since you need each value to be repeated for each row, but right now it's repeating the whole vector, not each value separately. Ronak's solution below splits the vector in two so the recycling happens separately. If this doesn't make sense, simplify your approach and assign one column at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
df2[paste(df1$realtime_period, df1$GDP, sep = "-")] <- as.list(df1$GDP)
```

Comment: This works, however I also want to do further calculations on these values on the same line of code.
I want each value to finally end up with the result of (df2$forecast-df1$GDP)^2, where df2$forecast is the respective value on each row in df2. I'm not sure if this is possible if we use as.list()

Comment: Do `df1` and `df2` have the same number of rows? In that case, you can do `df2[paste(df1$realtime_period, df1$GDP, sep = "-")] <- as.list((df2$forecast-df1$GDP)^2)` BTW it is easier to help if you share a reproducible example. A reproducible example is when you share data in a way that we can copy-paste into our R session and work with it . Usually it is done through `dput` i.e `dput(df1)` and `dput(df2)`. Looking at `str` of data doesn't really help.

Comment: No df1 and df2 don't have equal number of rows. I used the as.list() function to achieve the initial objective and did the calculation afterward.

Comment: I don't understand but I am glad that you were able to solve it.